# PHP - Write into MySQL Database to the correct path

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'd like to write into the red marked section in my MySQL Database. How to change my code to write to the correct path?

Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/coA1f.png

```
 $sql = "REPLACE INTO `faqconfig`(`config_value`)
        VALUES('" .mysql_real_escape_string( $version ). "')";
```

Comment: Is the row present? So do you want UPDATE the value? Or really insert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `config_name` is a primary key, you can use the following

```
INSERT INTO faqconfig (config_name, config_value) 
VALUES ('main.currentVersion', $version)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE config_value = $version;
```

Or

```
REPLACE INTO faqconfig (config_name, config_value)
VALUES ('main.currentVersion', $version);
```

The different between those two is that `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a INSERT if not exist, else UPDATE. While, `REPLACE INTO` is a DELETE if exists, then INSERT.

Comment: oh, made the same post ^^

Comment: @Dwza, yeah, it happens.

Answer (score 0):

may some like this...

```
$version = mysql_real_escape_string( $version );

INSERT INTO `faqconfig`
  (`config_name`,`config_value`)
VALUES
  ('main.currentVersion','{$version}')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `config_value`='{$version}';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
$sql = "UPDATE `faqconfig` set `config_value`='$version' WHERE config_name='main.currentVersion'";
```

Comment: Replace into is the same like insert into but replace the value if its exist.